# How to declare properties in an Angular constructor so they can be resolved

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-components

I am trying to figure out why I get the "Can't resolve all parameters..." error when adding properties to my constructor.  I seem to encounter this error a lot so I believe there is a fundamental misunderstanding on my part on how this works.

Note, I have read the angular guide on dependency injection but this doesn't seem to cover my use case.  The specific thing I'm trying to do is add an animation to my component so I am following along with this guide: https://angular.io/guide/animations.

The code below works: (in the sense that it doesn't blow up)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { trigger, state, style, animate, transition } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-payment',
  templateUrl: './new-payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-payment.component.scss'],
  animations: [
    trigger('loadState', [
        state('init', style({
            marginRight: '-400px',
            marginLeft: '400px'
        })),
        state('loaded', style({
            marginRight: '0px',
            marginLeft: '0px'
        })),
        transition('init => loaded', animate('100ms ease-in'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class NewPaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }
}
```

However the moment that i change the constructor to the following:

```
constructor(public state = 'init') { }
```

I get the error.

Now I don't completely understand why it is that I am adding this to the constructor other than that I am trying to mimic the example on the tutorial.  In the tutorial there is a parameter called 'state' which goes from a value of 'active' to 'inactive' which is what the animation is triggered on.  In my code I wanted the state parameter to be initialized as 'init' and then i was going to change it to 'loaded' in the ngOnInit() function.  The idea here being that my animation would happen only once every time the component was loaded.

What confuses me here is why is this variable 'state' even in the constructor params?  From what I've read the things that get put into the constructor are supposed to be dependencies but this is just a variable so i don't get it.

(Note, using Angular 5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a *component* (*directive*, *service*, *pipe*) and use it without creating it's instance using `new` - Angular automatically creates it's instance. Every parameter in the constructor of that component that Angular needs to resolve must be known to the Dependency Injection (DI) mechanism. DI tries to find that parameters in the *providers*, which are added into the *NgModule* or the component itself. DI mechanism tries to resolve the parameters based on

1) `type` - `public state: State`. DI tries to resolve the implementation of the type `State`. You can pass under the `State` type a primitive value, a class or something else. For more see **[Angular Providers](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#providers)**.

2) `InjectionToken` - `@Inject(APP_CONFIG) config`. DI tries to find what is under the token `APP_CONFIG`. For more see [**Angular Dependency injection tokens**](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#dependency-injection-tokens).

In your case DI mechanism does not know anything about the parameter `state` and for that it throws to you an exception. You haven't provided enough information about that - `type` or `InjectionToken`.

Comment: I believe I understand what you are saying here, however I suspect that is not the problem that i have.  As a test, i changed the constructor to this: constructor( public name: string ) and it still blows up.  What i am doing here is passing a primitive value right? so why doesn't it work?  Does it have something to do with the "implements OnInit" ? am i not validating to an interface or something?

Comment: `passing a primitive value right` - This part you didn't understand. You can pass primitive value under the `provider`. In this case DI tries to find information about `string` type and what is under it. You can for example try to add into the providers something like `{provide: string, useValue: 'MyName'}`. In this case DI will found info about `string` and gets the value `MyName` for it

Comment: I'm 95% sure i understand what you are saying here.... unfortunately my boss just came around and told me to do this with a css animation instead of the angular thing i was trying so I'm abandoning this task.